# How to calculate count of distinct id for weekly cohort?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

How to calculate the count of distinct id for the moving weekly cohort. 
For example, say there are records from 1st may,2019 to 31st may, 2019 now I want to calculate the count of distinct id present from

```
(distinct ids in 1st may,2019 to 7th may,2019)--> 2019-05-07         
(distinct ids in 2nd may,2019 to 8th may,2019)--> 2019-05-08
```

the weekly cohort will be changing everyday.

The sample data does look like one below:

```
date          id      country    language
01-05-2019    e002    US         EN
01-05-2019    a001    CH         LN
02-05-2019    f002    IN         EN
02-05-2019    e002    US         EN
```

i want the output to be like the one below:

```
date          count_ids   country   language
2019-05-07     22          US        EN
2019-05-07     11          CH        LN
2019-05-08     10          US        EN
```

table_a has distinct dates--->

```
CREATE TABLE table_b AS SELECT "date", 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT client_id) FROM raw_data where 
        TRUNC(raw_data.date) BETWEEN table_a.date - 7 AND table_a.date 
     group by date, language, country) 
AS count_ids FROM table_a;
```

Comment: Have you tried to write queries on your question? if yes, please share and so, will check for possible solutions. But honestly, you can use `count` `where clause` and `group by` and so on...

Comment: table_a has distinct dates--->
CREATE TABLE table_b 
AS
SELECT "date",
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT client_id)
        FROM raw_data
        where TRUNC(raw_data.date) BETWEEN table_a.date - 7 AND table_a.date
        group by date, language, country) AS count_ids
FROM table_a;

Comment: post your output record as per the records provided in input sample, here it is not cleared how you are getting `22` for `01-05-2019`.

Comment: it isn't actually 22 it is just some random numbers that i have put in the output...... basically it will have count of distinct ids for the last 7 days and will have language, country and date columns and a count_ids.

Comment: means i say that for `01-05-2019` we have 19 records, for `02-05-2019` we have 10 records, then in output `07-05-2019` has `29` in total which include both dates `01 & 02`, and for `08-05-2019` we have `10` on behalf of only `02`.

Comment: @DarkRob If 19 records are present on ```01-05-2019``` and 10 records on ```02-05-2019``` they may not add up to 29 records since i will considering weekly cohort some id's in ```01-05- 2019```  can also be present in ```02-05-2019``` and for the ```07-05-2019``` i will be considering count(distinct id's) for past 7 days i.e, from ```01-05-2019``` to ```07-05-2019``` whereas for ```08-05-2019```  i will be considering count(distinct id's) for past 7 days starting from ```02-05-2019``` to  ```08-05-2019```.

Comment: @murali: have you tried my ans.

Comment: @DarkRob Yes i did but it isn't working.

Comment: create a fiddle with your table structure and input data. or you may edit my ans for what it is showing on your record

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

This is the syntax of sql, may be this is not exactly what you want but this will surely give you an approach to get your desired result.

```
select (
      select Count(distinct t.id) from table as t 
          where t.date=tb.date and t.country=tb.country and t.language = tb.language 
          and t.date between t.date and dateadd(day,7,t.date) group by t.language, t.country  
       ) as Count, dateAdd(day, 7, tb.date) as Date, tb.country, tb.language 
from table as tb 
group by tb.date, tb.country, tb.language
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea.  Keep a running count of when a particular `id` is being counted.

To do this, an `id` "enters" the count when the id/country/language has not been seen for 7 days.  The `id` "exits" the count on the 8th day after not being seen.

The rest is aggregation and running totals.  You can calculate the intermediate values using window functions:

```
with tt as (
      select t.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by id, country, language
                             order by date
                            ) as prev_date,
             lead(date) over (partition by id, country, language
                              order by date
                             ) as next_date
      from t
     ),
     ee as (
      select id, country, language, date, 
             1 as enters, 0 as exits
      from tt
      where tt.prev_date is null or tt.prev_date < dateadd(day, -7, date)
      union all
      select id, country, language,
             dateadd(day, 8, date)
             0 as enters, 1 as exits
      from tt
      where tt.next_date is null or tt.date < dateadd(day, -7, next_date)
     )
select date, country, language, 
       sum(enters) as enters_on_day,
       sum(exits) as exits_on_day,
       sum(sum(enters)) as running_enters,
       sum(sum(exits)) as running_exits,
       (sum(sum(enters)) -
        sum(sum(exits))
       ) distinct_ids
from ee
group by date, country, language;
```